# Append row in pandas without iterrows()

Tags: python, pandas

Given the pandas dataframe with three loans, I need to add to the dataframe the payments, where the payment amount is total loan amount / number of payments.  If seq = 0, is the loan amount, else seq is the payment number. I can do this with `iterrows()` however the dataframe is very large and I would like to find a different solution.

This is my attempt:

```
import pandas as pd

rows  = [{'id': 'x1', 'seq': 0, 'amount': 2000, 'payments': 4 },
          {'id': 'x2', 'seq': 0, 'amount': 4000, 'payments': 2 },
          {'id': 'x3', 'seq': 0, 'amount': 9000, 'payments': 3 }]

df = pd.DataFrame(rows)
df2 = df.copy()

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    num = range(row['payments'])
    for i in num:
        payment_amount = row['amount'] / row['payments']
        row2 = {'id': row['id'], 'seq': i + 1 , 'amount': payment_amount, 'payments': 0 }
        df2 = df2.append(row2, ignore_index=True)
```

The result should be:

```
    id  seq amount  payments
0   x1  0   2000.0  4
1   x2  0   4000.0  2
2   x3  0   9000.0  3
3   x1  1   500.0   0
4   x1  2   500.0   0
5   x1  3   500.0   0
6   x1  4   500.0   0
7   x2  1   2000.0  0
8   x2  2   2000.0  0
9   x3  1   3000.0  0
10  x3  2   3000.0  0
11  x3  3   3000.0  0
```

However without using `iterrows()`. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

```
df_pay = df.iloc[df.index.repeat(df['payments'])]\
           .eval('amount = amount / payments')\
           .assign(payments=0)

df_pay['seq'] = df_pay.groupby('id').cumcount() + 1

pd.concat([df, df_pay], ignore_index=True)
```

Output:

```
    id  seq  amount  payments
0   x1    0  2000.0         4
1   x2    0  4000.0         2
2   x3    0  9000.0         3
3   x1    1   500.0         0
4   x1    2   500.0         0
5   x1    3   500.0         0
6   x1    4   500.0         0
7   x2    1  2000.0         0
8   x2    2  2000.0         0
9   x3    1  3000.0         0
10  x3    2  3000.0         0
11  x3    3  3000.0         0
```

---

Try this:

```
pd.concat([df, 
           df.iloc[df.index.repeat(df['payments'])]\
             .eval('amount = amount / payments')\
             .assign(payments=0)])
```

Output:

```
   id  seq  amount  payments
0  x1    0  2000.0         4
1  x2    0  4000.0         2
2  x3    0  9000.0         3
0  x1    0   500.0         0
0  x1    0   500.0         0
0  x1    0   500.0         0
0  x1    0   500.0         0
1  x2    0  2000.0         0
1  x2    0  2000.0         0
2  x3    0  3000.0         0
2  x3    0  3000.0         0
2  x3    0  3000.0         0
```

Trick using [`pd.Index.repeat`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Index.repeat.html) to generate payment records.

Comment: Shouldn't I avoid using `eval` if the number of rows is large? wouldn't `eval` be compiled for each row?

Comment: @ps0604 I am not aware of any performance issue with using `eval` however, you can do it after the fact also using standard pandas operations which are vectorized.

Comment: how do I get the seq? it shouldn't be always zero

Comment: @ps0604 See update.